# Bidirectional server/client communication in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a multiplayer game using JavaScript (no jQuery) and PHP, where most of the mechanics use AJAX calls. However, I need to determine when a user has left the game to update the player status on other players' screens (I assume by regular AJAX requests?). Also, once all players have left the game files (.txts) on the server need to be deleted.

I am using a free web hosting service which means I can't use WebSockets or cron jobs. I also don't want to use Node.js. Most of what I have read advise regularly timestamping with PHP sessions and this is fine, but I would like to know how to then *check* to see if the user/game has been inactive for a period of time.

Also, using `window.onbeforeunload` is too unreliable, in case browsers crash etc.

Comment: You're going to want to logout with [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon), using a [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) Event to logout. `onbeforeunload` doesn't always work and `navigator.sendBeacon` does not get cut off when there is no response, unlike a traditional `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Websockets is the correct solution here. Upgrade your hosting. Don't use the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Oops. I was using `onunload` and it worked on desktop Browsers, but then I saw the `visibilitychange` notes at the first link I posted. After some testing I now think you should use `navigator.sendBeacon` with a [pagehide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event) Event.

Comment: Should have no problem using websocket on the usual http ports (80, 443) whatever web host you are using:  see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512730/what-is-the-port-of-websocket).

Comment: @gWay the problem won't be ports. It'll be that on free/cheap shared hosting you usually aren't allowed to run your own daemons or Cron jobs, or other long running processes. This makes it pretty much impossible to run a reliable websocket server.

Comment: @ADyson You're right, I don't think it is possible in my situation... Perhaps that is the answer?

Comment: @goldenbanana42 well, it's not _impossible_ to do it with AJAX, but you have to take into consideration that it would be very inefficient also potentially unreliable, especially compared to websockets. If you can't run a socket server on your host, you could consider integrating with Azure SignalR - you can get a free instance of this if you don't use it heavily. While it's primarily designed for use with .NET applications, I remember reading in the documentation that it's possible to integrate it with other applications too. You'd have to look into the details, but it's something to look at.

Comment: e.g. https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/862 is one resource talking about it. You can no doubt find others providing more detail.

Comment: Needs Node.js I think? I might be wrong as I don't think I fully understand this!

Comment: No it doesn't need nodeJS at all. Not sure how you got that impression.

Comment: Found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-javascript) link by following the resource you sent? Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: That's one example, which happens to use nodeJS in an Azure function as the application component. But that doesn't mean it's the only thing you can use.

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to any other things? I would also like to accept an answer and you seem to know what you're doing...

Comment: It would probably make sense for your server-side PHP application to communicate with the SignalR instance through its REST API - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-rest-api . Client-side could connect to SignalR via websockets to send/receive messages. The PHP side would simply control which users go into which groups, and make any broadcasts to groups/users/all which need to happen as a result of other events in the application itself. I'm pretty sure this would work quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the wrong tool for the job.

Any kind of AJAX-based solution you attempt for this purpose is likely to very be inefficient, or unreliable, or probably both. If you have more than a tiny number of concurrent users, the sheer volume of AJAX requests would be likely to overwhelm the server and potentially bust your monthly quota. And as you've discovered, determining when someone has ended their session by closing the browser window is not straightforward or reliable.  I would advise against any such architecture.

Websockets is really the correct solution for real-time or near-real-time updates between client and server (and vice versa). It'a also easy for the socket server to know when someone has disconnected (which would occur if they close the window/tab).

So you could either upgrade your hosting so you're able to run a websocket server successfully, or try to integrate a websocket based solution hosted elsewhere, e.g. Azure SignalR or some similar product (I am not making specific recommendations in an answer, as that's regarded as off-topic).

Answer (score -2):

use an interval function and ping the php endpoint every second.
If it stops the User is out

Comment: This is horrifically inefficient

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but how would I actually implement this in PHP?

Comment: @ADyson is right its not the way its ment to be. But i guess your not a rockstar games developer developing on a new GTA... So for small purposes it will do its thing. just give every client a token. then use js intervall function to call a php endpoint sending the token. In php you will have a heartbeat of every client logged in

Comment: @Haennie maybe if you have only one or two users on a small site. But any more than that, and this quantity of AJAX requests will quickly overwhelm the server. Once every second is way too frequent. It's possible even with one page active, the requests could sometimes take more than 1 second to process (every HTTP connection has its own overhead, plus you have the I/O overhead of DB and file operations - and PHP doesn't do async I/O usually), so you could easily end up with a backlog of requests which kill the server and the page. This sort of crazy idea is exactly why websockets were invented

Comment: This would probably count towards the quota of hits per day the hosting has too...

Comment: your completely right on the technical part,  this has to be in mind while developing. But he wrote websockets are not an option, so it will not help him if you stuck on your opinion.    He is using a free web hosting service. Let him make his expierences and learn. Now he knows what the risk is.

Comment: @goldenbanana42 yes very call is a hit to a page on the server

Comment: @Haennie I think that an excess of calls would ban me from the hosting service... Not willing to make my own experiences in this case! Since yours is the only answer I will accept it if no others present themselves soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ADyson In that case there ought to be an answer saying it isn't possible, for anyone who might have this question later?